# adding an html into a Div

Tags: jquery, html, load

I want to load a few templates into a `div` element.

Every time I click on one template image it should load the HTML template into the `#contenidor_iframe` `div` element.

This is the container where the template needs to be loaded:

```
<div id="contenidor_iframe"></div>
```

This is the template code:

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../pluggins/dropzone/dropzone.css"> 
<div style=" margin:auto; text-align:center; ">
    <form action="http://www.torrentplease.com/dropzone.php" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="casella2"  style=" overflow:hidden;border:#FC3 2px dashed; width:300px; height:300px; display:inline-block; margin:10px;  " ></form>    
    <form action="http://www.torrentplease.com/dropzone.php" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="casella3"  style="border:#FC3 2px dashed; width:30%; height:109px; z-index:9999999 ; display:inline-block; "></form>     
</div>
<!-- ----------   DROPZONE  plugin   ------------------------   -->
<script src="../pluggins/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
```

This is the script that loads the template:

## JavaScript

```js
$("#caixa_plantilles").children().click(function(event) {
    var id_plantilla = event.target.id; // New selected target
    $.get('../plantilles/'+id_plantilla+'.html', function(data) {
        $('#contenidor_iframe').html(data);
        // alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});
```

The main document has Jquery libs, but there is no problem because if I open the plantilla1.html (the template) it works perfectly.

Comment: Care to format the code?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't understand the question

Comment: I can't find `#caixa_plantilles`

Comment: #caixa_plantilles is the box where are the template's image. If one of these are clicked then I must load the template into #contenidor_iframe. Do you understand now ,@Karl-AndréGagnon ?

Comment: @Blackersoul See the question now. It looks good. :) Indentation of code will make it understandable!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yes u're right !! Sorry I was late & I'm newbe, I'll keep it on my mind ;)

Comment: Any other idea about the trouble ?

Answer (score 0):

Surround the Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#caixa_plantilles").children().click(function(event) {
    var id_plantilla = event.target.id; // New selected target
    $.get('../plantilles/'+id_plantilla+'.html', function(data) {
        $('#contenidor_iframe').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```